# How to check and replace undefined and zero inside Javascript array map?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Following are the code snippet for the javascript map and join.
Here I want to check the object properties and if it contains the **undefined then display ""** and if the properties **contains the zero then display 0**.
Code is already running but when I see output into the console I did not get the value for undefined and 0.
Could some let me know what is the problem into the running code here.

```js
let userInfo = {
  "l_idReference": "205000",
  "l_Name": undefined,
  "l_totalDebitsAch": 1,
  "l_totalCreditsAch": 0,
  "l_totalCreditAmountAch": 0,
  "l_creationDateAndTime": "2019-10-11T00:00:00"
}
checkNullOrZero = (obj) => {
    //console.log(obj ,"OBJ")
    const output =  Object.keys(obj).map(col => {
      if(obj[col] === "" || obj[col] === 0){
        obj[col] = 0
      }
      return `<td>${obj[col] ? obj[col] : ""}</td>`
      
    }).join("")
    console.log(output)
  }
  
checkNullOrZero(userInfo)
```

Thanks.

Comment: `obj[col] ? obj[col] : ""` will turn any falsy value into an empty string. Since `0` is falsy, it would also be converted into nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.
Just check for the type undefined of the property.

```js
userInfo = {
  "l_idReference": "205000",
  "l_Name": undefined,
  "l_totalDebitsAch": 1,
  "l_totalCreditsAch": 0,
  "l_totalCreditAmountAch": 0,
  "l_creationDateAndTime": "2019-10-11T00:00:00"
}
checkNullOrZero = (obj) => {
  //     console.log(obj ,"OBJ")
  const output = Object.keys(obj).map(col => {
    if (obj[col] === "" || obj[col] === 0) {
      obj[col] = 0
    }
    if (obj[col] === undefined) {
      obj[col] = `""`
    }
    return `<td>${obj[col]}</td>`

  }).join("")
  console.log(output)
}

checkNullOrZero(userInfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

`'obj[col] ?'` Condition will be false when the obj[col] is equal to zero,

So you should change your condition.

Try this :

```js
  let userInfo = {
      "l_idReference": "205000",
      "l_Name": undefined,
      "l_totalDebitsAch": 1,
      "l_totalCreditsAch": 0,
      "l_totalCreditAmountAch": 0,
      "l_creationDateAndTime": "2019-10-11T00:00:00"
    }
    checkNullOrZero = (obj) => {
        //console.log(obj ,"OBJ")
        const output =  Object.keys(obj).map(col => {
          if(obj[col] === "" || obj[col] === 0){
            obj[col] = 0
          }
          return `<td>${obj[col]!= undefined ? obj[col] : obj[col] == 0 ? "0" : ""}</td>`
          
        }).join("")
        console.log(output)
      }
      
    checkNullOrZero(userInfo)
```

Comment: The code may be correct, but please add an explanation of how it solves the problem, so that the op can learn from it